# Bind viewmodel to ui after ajax call succeeds Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I have a selectall toggle checkbox and checkbox in each row of data .

Now the data which is returned from the server doesnt have `isSelected` Observable. I have added 'isSelected' observable for each row . But the `isSelected` observable doesnt get bound to  the checkboxes in each row .

Here is the viewmodel :

```
var folderViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.SelectedFolder = ko.observable();
    self.Mails = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedMail = ko.observable();
    self.SelectAll = ko.observable(false);

    self.navigate = function (folder) {
        self.SelectedFolder(folder);
        //$.get('/Api/MailBox', { folder: folder }, self.Mails);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Api/Mailbox",
            data: { folder: folder },
            success: function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Mails);
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Mails(), function (mail) {
                    mail.isSelected = ko.observable(true);
                    mail.isSelected.subscribe(function (myvalue) {
                        console.log(myvalue);
                    });
                });
                console.log(ko.toJSON(self.Mails()));
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert("No Mail");
                }
            }
        });

        //ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Mails);
        //console.log(ko.toJSON(self.Mails));
    };

    self.SelectAll.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Mails(), function (mail) {
            console.log(mail.isSelected());
            mail.isSelected(newValue);

        });
        console.log(newValue);
    }, self);

    this.navigate("Inbox");
};
ko.applyBindings(new folderViewModel());
```

And here is the binding .

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: SelectAll"/>
            @*<input type="checkbox" />*@
        </th>
        <th>
            From
        </th>
        <th>
            To
        </th>
        <th>
            Subject
        </th>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach:Mails">
    <tr data-bind="click:$root.navigateToMail">
        <td style="width: 15px">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.isSelected">
            @*<input type="checkbox">*@
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: From">
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: To">
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Subject">
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: MailDate">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The checkbox  `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.isSelected">` is not getting bound to the ajax data in `mails.isSelected=ko.obsevable(true)`. What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, kuddos for using the [learn.knockoutjs.com](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) example, amazing resource.

Your error is a common pitfall in KnockoutJS: you are modifying your model without updating the observables that are binded to it. See the following lines -

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Mails);
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Mails(), function (mail) { ... });
```

If you see, you are first creating your model for the mails and THEN adding up an extra observable. To which context this observable should be attached to? Without updating the values of each mail, your `mail.isSelected` is never added to the mail object.

There are two ways to solve this. The first one, you update the mail model in the forEach array:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Mails(), function (mail, index) { 
    // Add up the isSelected observable
    self.Mails()[index] = mail; 
});
```

This has a performance gotcha on observable arrays that you can read [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html). Basically, you want to create a temp array and update the entire observable array than call the `Mails()` each time.

The other way is quite simple: swap the order of how are you creating the mail model:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Mails(), function (mail) { ... });
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Mails);
```

FIRST, you are attaching to a data object your observable and THEN you are telling to your viewmodel "Hey! We got a new model to save it has this properties from `data` PLUS an observable isSelected I just added, care to bind it up?"

That being said, the property in the HTML is `checked: isSelected` and not `checked: $root.isSelected`, which was the reason why it was sort of working on the SelectAll (sort of), as the isSelected was being binded to your ViewModel instead of your mail model. You could had figure it out debugging with this handy statement:

```
// In any row inside your data
<td data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)">DEBUG DATA</td>
```

That should be it, you can see your code working here as well as all its solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jjperezaguinaga/VTuHA/. I added some sample data to play around (with the `/echo/json/` feature from JsFiddle) and removed some stuff, as well as an extra column that I used to debug with the last code I put. In this last column you can see the value `isSelected` being updated every time you click on a checked box.

Comment: excellent answer but care to explain one part . I understud the fact that you actually attached observable property to the data and then mapped it with knockout mapping . Sorry for being noob but arent both of them the same thing ? if u create an observable array first and then attach the observable property ( which is obviously what I did but wasn't working ) . So care to explain what was my fault here ?

Comment: No problem, and there's no noob questions :) One thing is the ViewModel (think of your entire function object, the one accessed with the `$root` tag and the other is your Mail Model, which is just an expression to describe a specific class with a bunch of attributes. Your ViewModel has a collection (ko.observableArray) of Mail Models; your problem was that you were binding the `isSelected` to your ViewModel (`$root.isSelected` worked) while you needed to bind it to each Mail Model and the proper scope.

Comment: This is related the famous `this` word in Javascript. What was the context of the ko.observable when you appended it to the Mail object in the foreach? It was the ViewModel, so you were binding it to your entire ViewModel instead of the Model you wanted. Btw, Model is just a syntax copied from Backbone that represents a "class", it's not really used in KnockoutJS; hopefully the use of this word helped you to see that your mail is a specific Object from a specific class and not to confuse you :)

Comment: oh okay thanks . I think  I get it . I was actually binding it to the base function but not to each mail object . I need to do a research I guess before I get sure . However thanks a lot . I would keep your statements as reference while considering that in future too :)

Comment: That's correct, and no problem, feel free to continue asking around SO, we'll help as we can.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `isSelected` added on each `mail` item, not in the `root` view model?. If so your binding should just be:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected">
```

NOTE: I also don't see a `navigateToMail` method available in the `root` view model, which will also cause problems.

Comment: I actually Did that . But on that it says isSelected is not defined